# Why mysql "ENGINE=InnoDB" doesn't work with joomla 3 installation

Tags: mysql, installation, joomla3.0, database-engine, database-create

I got the solution for joomla 3 installation problem(installation stucks in creating databases) in stackoverflow.

The solution that to **replace "ENGINE=innoDB" with "ENGINE=MyIsam"** 
  in

`joomla-folder\installation\sql\mysql\joomla.sql, it works well.`

Anyone know the reason why innoDB is not working with joomla 3 installation.

And do I need to restore the engine from "MyIsam" to "innoDB" again(after installed successfully)?

Comment: Did you check which engines your MySQL installation supports?

Comment: @Mjh You are right, mysql version might be the issue. if mysql version is 5.5 or latest , then there will be no issue it seems.

Answer (score 1):

It is because MyIsam is supported and compatible more with Joomla. You can check [here](http://www.balbooa.com/knowledgebase/32-documentation-faq-joomla/210-why-joomla-3-installation-freezes-at-creating-database-table)

> And do I need to change the engine to "innoDB" again(after installed
>   successfully)

If you have changed it while installing it then there is no need to change it again.